# Синхронизация Sqlite через файл на Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Сервер(не мой) присылает на моё Android устройство файл с расширением db, как с его помощью синхронизировать SQLITe, то есть кодом открыть. Подскажите пожалуйста) Пытался :

```
DB_PATH="/storage/sdcard0/";
mDataBase.close();
mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH + Ssss, null);
```

и ни как. Возможно проблема в пути -разные проги показывают по разному

Comment: Сервер присылает сам что ли? Может ваше приложение скачивает его с сервера? Тогда используйте путь, по которому сохраняли этот файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File db_file = new File("path_to_file");
database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db_file, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

Если вы хотите провести синхронизацию с уже имеющейся базой, то используйте attach

```
database.execSQL("attach '" + db.getPath() + "' as source");
```

и обращайтесь ко второй базе через это имя

```
cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from source.table_name", null, null);
```

Ну и, как выяснилось в комментариях, важно не забыть прописать в манифесте разрешение READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и проверять что оно выдано во время исполнения :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но ругается на rawExecSQL, мол нету такого, может вы имели в виду execSQL?

Comment: Вы правы, я просто пользуюсь cipher библиотекой, там немного методы отличаются. Поправил ответ

Comment: увы, но оно не синхронизирует - данные как были старыми, так и остались(((

Comment: А вы написали синхронизацию-то?) Я вам показал инструмент, позволяющий работать одновременно с двумя базами. Скопировать данные вам придется самому

Comment: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database - не открывает теперь чето

Comment: И что вы хотите получить в ответ на эту информацию?) Или создайте новый вопрос с подробностями, или разберитесь сами, одного кода ошибки нам тут явно не хватит

Comment: Вообщем, проблема была не в базе данных, а в том, что я опять забыл про разрешения <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />. Можете добавить в свой ответ ещё и про них ?